# mouseover event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to create a program with jQuery that would essentially create a sketchpad where each box turns red when the mouse hovers over it.

```js
function createGrid(rows, columns){
 var container = '<div id="container"></div>';
 $('body').append(container);
 var row = ('<div class="row"></div>');
 for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  $('#container').append(row);
 }
 var column = ('<div class="square"></div>');
 for(var a = 0; a < columns; a++) {
  $('.row').append(column);
 }
}

function newGrid(){
 $('#container').remove();
 var rows = prompt("How many rows?");
 var columns = prompt("How many columns?");
 createGrid(rows, columns);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 createGrid(16,16);
 $('#newgrid').on('click', function(){
  newGrid();
 });
 $('.square').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).addClass('painted');
 });
});
```

```css
.square{
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.painted{
 background-color: red;
}

button{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Draw</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="draw.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="draw.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="newgrid">New Grid</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

When you click the "new grid" button, the grid should adapt to the new grid size parameters. However, after that happens, the grid isn't responding to my mouseover event. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mnfm361u/1/ like this? You should bind mouseover to parent, because of dynamically created elements...

Answer (score 0):

After you recreate the grid, elements with the attached event handlers are lost.

You need to rebind the event handlers every time the grid is recreated:

```
function createGrid(rows, columns){
    var container = $('<div id="container"></div>'); // make it a jQuery object
    $('body').append(container);
    var row = ('<div class="row"></div>');
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        $('#container').append(row);
    }
    var column = ('<div class="square"></div>');
    for(var a = 0; a < columns; a++) {
        $('.row').append(column);
    }
    // attach event handler only to the ancestors of the new container
    // so you don't add additional event handlers to could be existing other grids
    container.find('.square').on('mouseover', function(){ 
        $(this).addClass('painted');
    });
}
```

You could also just use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.square', function(){
    $(this).addClass('painted');
});
```

In this case you don't even need to add it into ready callback.